# Get error codes while using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I run an SQL script using psql.exe I am not getting error codes when an error occurs. Is there any way to get the psql error codes?

I tried setting VERBOSITY to 'verbose' like this,  but no use:

```
\set VERBOSITY 'verbose'
```

I am using psql of version psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.2.

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you as "the answer".

Answer (score 19):

Get rid of the quotes:

```
test=# \set VERBOSITY verbose
test=# select broken;
ERROR:  42703: column "broken" does not exist
LINE 1: select broken;
               ^
LOCATION:  transformColumnRef, parse_expr.c:766
```