# How to get the postgresql error code for current query

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql for the following query:

`CREATE TABLE t(x INT UNIQUE, y varchar(12) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY);`

This one gives the error message:

`ERROR:  identity column type must be smallint, integer, or bigint`

How can I know what's the error code for this message?

Reference: [postgresql error code list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/errcodes-appendix.html).

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465047/get-error-codes-while-using-psql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get error codes while using psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465047/get-error-codes-while-using-psql)

Comment: How you get that number depends on the programming language you are using. In Java/JDBC this is e.g. available through the SQLException instance.

Comment: Exactly. Please add a tag for the programming language and API used.

Answer (score 0):

For getting more information about a SQL query you can use `EXPLAIN` or `ANALYZE` features. Just add the buzzword before your sql and execute it.
Sidenote: This will not automatically make the error be visible better.

Anyway your issue is that you are using `IDENTITY` as ID generation which uses numeric values which increase by a sequence/...
For a text id you need to use the extension uuid-ossp or if you're on postgres 13+ you can directly call `gen_random_uuid()` which will lead to this creation:

```
id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY
```